# Better/shorter formulation for "teaching time"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, time, dates

I have a label *Teaching time* that reflects the time-slot of the day or week a lecture would be taught on. For example, morning, afternoon, evening, weekend...

Is there any better (shorter) British English formulation to describe this?

Comment: "class time", normally, I think.

Comment: We used to call them [periods](https://scheduling.rutgers.edu/scheduling/class-scheduling/standard-course-periods). "who's teaching first period English this year?"

Comment: Thanks @PhilSweet I think it makes sense but it clashes a bit with the notion of "study period" being often used as "from this day to day" or "week X to week Y"? (That's how we use period in our context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classtime** (or class-time, class time) — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/classtime)

> *noun* 1. The time devoted to or prepared for a lesson at school or elsewhere; schooltime
>
> Still most commonly encountered as two separate words, rather than in its hyphenate or compounded form.

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by comment on an ancient post, but for anyone who comes across this in the future: usually this term refers to *time spent in class **in general***, rather than "the time of the [specific] class [period]". Certainly in the UK **period** is more common for OP's usage.

Comment: @WillCrawford Yeah, that's right. Would be nice if you could add that as an answer as well. :)